# Add a new element into one array recursively

Tags: php, arrays

How to add a new element into one array recursively,
The case like this,

```
$insertNew = "Another Value";
```

Main Array :

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
   [3] => 4
)
```

I need an array like below becaue I want to make a insert batch in mysql

```
        [
          ['Another Value', 1],
          ['Another Value', 2],
          ['Another Value', 3],
          ['Another Value', 4],
        ]
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this simplest one will be helpful

**Solution 1:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805384)

```
$result=array();
$insertNew = "Another Value";
foreach($yourArray as $value)
{
    $result[]=array($insertNew,$value);
}
print_r($result);
```

**Solution 2:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805397)

```
$insertNew = "Another Value";
$result=  array_map(function($value) use ($insertNew){
    return array($insertNew,$value);
}, $array);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but too much line I guess. I do this all the time, I use forecah then so so, I dont know why people down vote my question because need more elegant way.